# regular expressions dial code patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I want to transform dialing numbers from a range of inputs that are varied

If I want to take numbers such as

```
 +65 12345678
 +44 12345678
 +852 12345678
```

then transform them to become for all +65 numbers

```
12345678
```

+44 numbers become

```
001 44 12345678
```

then +852 numbers become

```
*852 12345678
```

and at the same time removing spaces and other funny chars such as hyphens or periods ("-", ".") what is the best regex to do this or the best solution in c#?

Comment: Four separate regular expressions, one that performs each task, executed separately. (The fourth taking care of removing hyphens, periods, spaces, etc. remaining after the first three have done their work.) Have you tried to do any single one of them yet?

Comment: just starting, I can run 3 but wondered if there are some cleaner ways to do this

Comment: "Cleaner" is "easiest to code and maintain". Trying to do it in a single step isn't "clean" at all, and would be extremely difficult to modify in the future.

Comment: ok, assume I have 100 international dialing codes

Comment: Then you would have to tell us the 100 different rules you would apply to them, and yet the recommendation would apply: doing 100 different regex rather than having a gargantuan one.

Comment: First you sanitize the input - regex search + replace any funny chars you don't want in your input. Then you use another regex to check the number format and grab the dialing code. Then use a lookup table (hash table/map) to find the replacement rule regex. Then do the conversion. If you ever need to add a new dialing code conversion rule or modify an existing one, there is one place where you do it and change only that specific rule without modifying other parts of the code.

Comment: e.g.  Regex.Replace("+65 123-4.5-6-7",@"[^\d]","");

Comment: ma3x ok, so how to do?

Comment: OK. Assume you [edit] your question to post your actual requirements, and some effort to solve it yourself, instead of trying to discuss it in the comments. :-) You specifically asked about performing four distinct operations, so if your question is different than that edit to ask it properly.

Comment: Are you dealing with phone numbers? if so, i would recommend NOT use your own regex's, and instead use a phone number library

Comment: yes dealing with phone numbers

Comment: what phone number libraries are there to choose from?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using *delegate*:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\+(\d{2,3})[-. ](\d{8})");
string result = reg.Replace(input, delegate(Match m) {
    switch (m.Groups[1].Value) {
        case "65":  return m.Groups[2].Value;
                    break;
        case "44":  return "001 44 " + m.Groups[2].Value;
                    break;
        case "852": return "*852 " + m.Groups[2].Value;
                    break;
        default:    return m.Value;
                    break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I get the idea. I was never going to get that in a million years

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I went for the ported version of google libphonenumber

bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home

```
    private DialedNumber applyCallPattern(string noToDial)
    {

        noToDial = noToDial.Replace("callto:", ""); 
       //libphone removes text anyway so this line above is not needed


        PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
        string dc = "SG";
        if (AutoDialer.Properties.Settings.Default.BaseOffice == "Hong Kong")
        {
            dc = "HK";
        }
        PhoneNumber pn = phoneUtil.Parse(noToDial, dc);
        string rc = phoneUtil.GetRegionCodeForNumber(pn);
        string dialingNumber = null;



        if (rc == "SG")
        {
            dialingNumber = phoneUtil.Format(pn, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
            if (AutoDialer.Properties.Settings.Default.BaseOffice == "Hong Kong")
            {
                dialingNumber = "*65" + dialingNumber;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == "HK")
        {
            dialingNumber = phoneUtil.Format(pn, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
            if (AutoDialer.Properties.Settings.Default.BaseOffice == "Singapore")
            {
                dialingNumber = "*852" + dialingNumber;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            dialingNumber = phoneUtil.Format(pn, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
            dialingNumber = dialingNumber.Replace("+", "001");
        }
        dialingNumber = dialingNumber.Replace(" ", "");
        DialPopup popup = new DialPopup();
        popup.label1.Text = "Calling: " + dialingNumber;
        popup.Show();

        DialedNumber dn = new DialedNumber(dialingNumber, phoneUtil.GetRegionCodeForNumber(pn), phoneUtil.GetNumberType(pn).ToString(), DateTime.Now, false);
        Program.lastNoDialed = dialingNumber;
        return dn;
    }
```

libphonenumber rocks and makes it SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO much easier, so thanks for the suggestion Alden, really helped.

For anyone else doing this task, I havent found anything anywhere near as good as the libphonenumber ported version. It strips out any junk and totally nails everything I needed with ease.  Also able to get line type (mobile, fixed, premium etc), region code for dialing plus more.  Job done thanks Google.